# How to test if a feature is installed in a karaf console script?

Tags: scripting, console, osgi, karaf

I need to write a karaf console script that uninstalls a feature, if it is present on karaf 3.0.4.

So far I have not found any direct references mentionend in the documentation (https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-3.0.x/developers-guide/scripting.html). Using `shell:env ?` always returns `null` as the value and I'm not sure if `?` is a supported environment variable name in karaf.

So how can execute a karaf command if a feature is present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to test if a feature is installed in a karaf console script in version 3.0.4. This is because the [commands for scope `feature`](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-3.0.x/commands/commands.html#feature) do not  return anything to the console (see the [source code](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=karaf.git;a=tree;f=features/command/src/main/java/org/apache/karaf/features/command;hb=20cb40c3a1fe18cfb8dca3cd28b4c3090acef837)).

The workaround is to [deploy another command](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-3.0.x/developers-guide/extending.html) to karaf that returns a boolean to the console and use this in a script.