# How to continously deploy a feature to karaf?

Tags: deployment, osgi, continuous-deployment, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I want to continously deploy a feature to ServiceMix 6.0, which is based on Karaf 3.0.4.

I first tried this using the karaf console. However there are some problems. It is for a standard karaf installation not possible to determine on the [karaf console](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/developers-guide/scripting.html) if a feature is already installed (see my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076009/how-to-test-if-a-feature-is-installed-in-a-karaf-console-script) on this). The other problem with the karaf console is that it doesn't support exit codes. So it is not possible to determine reliably if a feature installation was successfully finished.

I then [installed hawtio](http://hawt.io/getstarted/index.html#Using_Fuse__Fabric8__Apache_Karaf_or_Apache_Servicemix) and tried to use the exposed JMX beans via jolokia/REST that is bundled with hawtio. The problem here is that karaf 3.0.x is [unable to update a feature](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-3.0.x/users-guide/provisioning.html#Featuresupgrade). Therefore features must be uninstalled first. However the [FeatureService](https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/karaf-3.0.x/features/core/src/main/java/org/apache/karaf/features/FeaturesService.java) only offers the possibility to uninstall an explicitly specified feature. But when a previous version of the feature was installed, subfeatures were installed with it. They also need an upgrade and therefore be uninstalled first. So I would need a way to iterate over the subfeatures of a feature, which I do not have.

So how can continous deployment of features to karaf 3.0.x be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first try we have implemented is a bash script. The biggest problem is uninstalling the old version. Therefore we have set up a convention for the names of the feature and it's subfeatures. So we can use the following to find already installed features:

```bash
features=$(echo "feature:list" | ssh -p $smx_ssh_port $smx_user@$smx_host | grep -h "<feature-name-convention-regex>.*|.*x.*|" | cut -f1 -d" " | tr '\n' ' ')
```

This can then be passed to `feature:uninstall` and can also be used for detecting if features were installed after the call to `feature:repo-add -i`.

The remaining problem is that we are unable to reference 3rd-party subfeatures because they won't be uninstalled when an updated version needs to be installed and we can't be sure if all of the subfeatures have been successfully installed.

Answer (score 0):

For karaf 3 there is no good way to update features.

This is already a little better for karaf 4. It allows to update a feature repo and you can then simply install the feature again. It will detect that the feature has changed and do the necessary changes in bundles.